# mongodb equivalent of SELECT field AS `anothername`

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mapping, aggregation-framework

what is the mongodb equivalent of the MySQL query

```
SELECT username AS  `consname` FROM  `consumer`
```

Comment: aggregation framework $proejct is the only way

Comment: Best to just fix up the data using whatever client/driver you're using. Some can do this as a feature of the driver.

Comment: `db.consumer.find().toArray().map(function (doc) { doc.consname=doc.username; delete doc.username; return doc; });`

Comment: @hgoebl: find() returns a collection, and there is no toArray method (at least in Meteors mongodb version 2). But you can do a forEach on the collection.

Comment: @westor possible that I'm wrong or the `toArray()` is only in mongo shell or in an older version of the native driver. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: @westor: what's up with Meteor? The OP asked about MongoDB, not Meteor. find() returns a cursor, which has a [`map` method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#map).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As it was mentioned by sammaye, you have to use [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) in [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to rename fields.

So in your case it would be:

```
db.consumer.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "consname": "$username"
    }}
])
```

Cool thing is that in 2.6.x version aggregate returns a cursor which means it behaves like find.

You might also take a look at [$rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator to permanently change schema.

Comment: This helped me in flattening array values from `$lookup` aggregate function after spending a few hours of search. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Salvador Dali's answer is fine, but not working in meteor versions before 3.0.
I currently try meteor, and their build in mongodb is in version 2.
The way I solved this is like this:

```
var result = []:
db.consumer.forEach( function(doc) {
   result.push({
     consname:doc.username
   });
});
```

Comment: But OP no mention Meteor